# SQL Select With Distinct, Top, and Count?

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I'm using an MS Access database for a simple inventory application. Whenever one of the entries in the database is changed, it updates a column in that row called LastDate.

I currently have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 LastDate from Inventory ORDER BY LastDate DESC;
```

Works great. It selects the 10 most recent unique dates listed in the LastDate column and returns them.

I now want to refine the select query though and I am having trouble doing it. I only want to return the top 10 distinct records, as long as there at least X number of records matching. I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 LastDate from Inventory WHERE Count(LastDate) > 3 ORDER BY LastDate DESC;
```

But it obviously doesn't work. Any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last 10 dates that have at least four entries each? Aggregate per date and count.

```
SELECT TOP 10 LastDate 
FROM Inventory 
GROUP BY LastDate
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4
ORDER BY LastDate DESC;
```